# Select multiple options in a materialize select box

Tags: jquery, materialize

I would like to select multiple options from a materialize selectbox through jquery.

The selection is done as an "edit" document modal window. So i want to show all the departments the document shows up for.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the my code

HTML

```
<select id="edit_document_departments" name="departments[]" required multiple>
    <option value="" disabled>Select Some Departments</option>
        @foreach($data->departments as $department)
            <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}</option>
        @endforeach
 </select>
```

JQUERY

```
   let departmentsArray = departments.split(', '); //Help Desk, HR, Project Team

    $.each(departmentsArray, function (index, value) {
        $('#edit_document_departments').find('option[text="'+value+'"]').prop('checked', true);
    });

    $('#edit_document_departments').material_select();

    $('#editDocumentModal').modal('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

It will do the selecting the checkboxes automatically. You just have to set the values. Try:

```
$('#edit_document_departments').material_select('destroy');
$('#edit_document_departments').val(departmentsArray);
$('#edit_document_departments').material_select();
```

Comment: Well, your destroy mention gave me an idea. I'll just build the list dynamically. I was really hoping to not do that. Not that I am lazy or anything.... ;)